# DDD and EventSourcing how to detect redundant events in design

Tags: events, architecture, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

We are developing our application with help of EventSourcing. Let's imagine we have an Aggregate "InvestorAccount" - holds information about Investor's  portfolio (stocks).

We have 2 options which events should we have:

1. `InvestorAccountCreated` event
2. `SharesBought` event
3. `SharesSold` event

or

1. `SharesBought` event
2. `SharesSold` event

We are not sure we need `InvestorAccountCreated` event. We can use just `SharesBought` as a first initial event. The idea is - when investor bought shares - we automatically create account for him. Right now it's doesn't make sense to have empty Invetor's account (with out shares) and we don't see bebefits of having `InvestorAccountCreated` event, but may be we still should have it, because it will be useful in the future?

Do we need to to have `InvestorAccountCreated` ? And why?

Comment: An investor may buy many shares in his/her lifecycle. If you go with creating investor account with share purchase, don't you end up introducing logic to _distinguish the first share purchase_ in the `SharesBought` event handler? It may have consequences.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is (as nearly always in DDD): it depends.

If there's no concept in the domain of an investor account which has never owned a share, then it's probably not a great idea to have an `InvestorAccountCreated` event, because that makes the state of an investor account which has never owned a share derivable from persisted events and forces a runtime validation that no `InvestorAccountCreated` event is issued without immediately (or even better atomically) issuing a `SharesBought` event.

That said, by not having an `InvestorAccountCreated` event, you are making it more difficult if it turns out that, actually, the domain needs to model an investor account that hasn't bought a share.  The event can be added, but you've given up the ability to guarantee that for every investor account there's exactly one `InvestorAccountCreated` (and thus, for instance, you can't count the number of investor accounts by counting the `InvestorAccountCreated` events).